# Display PDF stream returned from controller using jquery in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, window

I have a controller action which reads a `.pdf` file from azure blobstorage and returns stream object to the `$.ajax()` method.

Controller returns

```
var stream = blobStorage.OpenRead(filepath);
await FileAsync(stream, "application/pdf");
```

Ajax call and response

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/PDFfile",
        data: { 'id': Id },
        dataType: "application/pdf",
        traditional: true,
        complete: function(data) {
            var w = window.open("data:application/pdf, " + escape(data.responseText));
            w.document.write(data.responseText);
            w.document.close();
        }
    });
```

However, if the call is to the same controller action as shown, the file is displayed correctly.

```
<a class="pull-right btn-link" target="_blank" data-bind="attr: { href: '/PDFfile/' + Id }"></a>
```

It may appear as a duplicate question but none of the solutions worked for me.
The output I am getting is as shown.[image]

Comment: And what would you like to get instead? A file download dialog? A rendered version of the pdf with pdf.js or a rendered version with a browser addon like adobe reader?

Comment: @JamesBlond I woud like to view pdf file in the browser (in correct format) and be able to print/ download

Comment: So your users all should have an installed adobe reader add-on? If the pdfs are not very complex I would look at pdf.js so you are not depending on the add-on.

Comment: @JamesBlond I do not think that is the issue. Please check the edit. The file is viewed successfully if the call to controller is directly from anchor tag

Comment: I know that this is not the issue. I'm just saying that many browsers will not show that pdf as you expect it, since quite a lot of people have pdf rendering in their browser disabled and pdf.js might be an alternative which would help with the issue as well. But anyway, it looks like the browser is missing the mime type, even though you set it in the open method.

Comment: thanks @JamesBlond

Comment: It is just the same issue I have here :)

Answer (score 2):

I couldnt find a exact answer to this question. I found a bunch of different questions.
I finally was able to piece together by using `fetch`.
You need to accept type `'arraybuffer'`, then you turn into a blob with `resopnse.blob()`. Then you can open the blob in a new window.

```
          fetch('/post/url', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            Accept: 'arraybuffer',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        //you need to use json here
                        body: JSON.stringify({ items: [{ ItemId: 3, Quantity: 40 }], fileId: 2 });
                    })
                        .then(response => response.blob())
                        .then(data => {
                            var popup = window.open(URL.createObjectURL(data), "height=500,width=750);

                   });
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you just use standard HTML? There's no need for Javascript here (as you created a standard `<a>` tag for initial trigger of action).

Something like:

```
<form action="/PDFfile" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="submit" value="Show me the file in a new tab/window!"/>
</form>
```

Notes:

- be sure to set an header `Content-Type: application/pdf` in your Azure script, so that the browser will know it's a PDF
- as @JamesBlond stated you may not see it if you don't have a browser's plugin to read PDF. But you'll have a nice download box, and the new tab will be closed automatically